# Cannot JSON decode japanese in Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, json, windows, unicode

I have the following (example) python file, written in Notepad++ with encoding set to UTF-8. (Windows platform, if that matters)

```
import json

test = '''{ "data":{
    "testdata": [
        {
            "name":"空集合"
        }
     ]}
 }'''

result = json.loads(test)
print(result)
```

When I try to run it (from command line), I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Users\Kyte\Desktop\asdf\app.py", line 14, in <module>
    print(result)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\encodings\cp850.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 33-35: character maps to <undefined>
```

I can't, for the life of me, figure out the error, since this is valid json written in (presumably) valid encodings that match the default options. Any ideas?

Comment: That is down to your windows console limitations, where are you running it from?

Comment: Is that Notepad's code set to UTF-8? or is it the encoding line at the top of the python program which is set to UTF-8? Windows is natively UTF-16, so that could cause some confusion.

Comment: In this case the platform probably does matter. Your program works perfectly on my Ubuntu PC.

Comment: Yes, the file is in UTF-8. It's NPP's default and I double checked to make sure. I run the file by going to cmd and running it as "app.py". I can't afford to change OSs right now, so gonna need a Windows solution.

Comment: If you print with encoding='utf-8' directly to a file it will avoid console terminal interference.  Interactively try using Spyder because its console is set to utf-8 even on Windows.

Comment: Good enough for me. Thanks. Mind making it an answer so I can accept it? (I also realized I was misunderstanding the error and thinking it was in the parse process rather than in the printing to the console. God this has been a bad day.)

Comment: The standard way of writing to the console uses 8-bit string APIs -- what Windows calls the OEM/ANSI codepages. That's great if the terminal/console supports UTF-8. The Windows console does not (using the UTF-8 codepage, 65001, is buggy). Instead you can use the native wide-character API of Windows, which is based on UTF-16. Since you're using Python 3, you can try [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console) to make `sys.stdin` and `sys.stdout` use the wide-character console API.